# Screenshot of only the visible desktop

Tags: java, screenshot, jna

I'm using JNA / *CGWindowListCreateImage* to take a screenshot on an OS X system.

The code is mostly taken from this question:

[Invalid memory access of location with Rococoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655145)

My problem is that although it "works" it does take a copy of an entire desktop, whose size changes depending on the position of other windows (for example if another window is partially onscreen, then the part that is *not* onscreen will contribute to make the "desktop" screenshot larger).

So on a 1680x1050 I get "desktop screenshot" (well, not really), that can be 1714x1084 pixels etc.

I take it that by passing the correct origin / bounds my problem shall go away but I don't know how to get that info, especially not using JNA.

Here's basically what I've got:

```
final int windowIdDesktop = 0;

QuartzLibrary.CGRect bounds = new QuartzLibrary.CGRect.CGRectByValue();
bounds.origin = new QuartzLibrary.CGPoint();
bounds.origin.x = 0;
bounds.origin.y = 0;
bounds.size = new QuartzLibrary.CGSize();
bounds.size.width = 0;
bounds.size.height = 0;
ID imageRef = QuartzLibrary.INSTANCE.CGWindowListCreateImage(bounds,QuartzLibrary.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, windowIdDesktop, QuartzLibrary.kCGWindowImageDefault);
```

Apparently someone who had the same issue, but in Objective-C, used the following technique to compute the correct bounds:

> the benefit of the archives and anyone else having a similar issue,
>   here is how I calculate the bounding box:

```
NSRect desktopRect = NSZeroRect; for (NSScreen *screen in [NSScreen screens]) { desktopRect = NSUnionRect(desktopRect, [screen frame]); }
```

Why is this necessary and how can I translate this to JNA?  All I need to know is what the origin of the visible portion of the screen is (at least I think so)

The *CGWindowListCreateImage* states the following:

```
Setting
   `screenBounds' to `CGRectInfinite' will include all the windows on the
   entire desktop. Setting `screenBounds' to `CGRectNull' will use the
   bounding box of the specified windows as the screen space rectangle.
```

But I really don't know how I can "simulate" or pass either *CGRectInfinite* nor *CGRectNull* to my JNA code.  I'm not even sure it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using the Java-provided methods for obtaining the display size?  Java provides the following (for a single display):

```
// Get the size of the default display
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

If more than one display is available, this gets the size of each display:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();

// Get size of each display
for (int i=0; i<gs.length; i++) {
    DisplayMode dm = gs[i].getDisplayMode();
    int screenWidth = dm.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = dm.getHeight();
}
```